# PostgreSQL Searching whole words in a string regardless of order regex?

Tags: regex, postgresql, search

Is there anyway to implement this kind of search functionality using query and regex?

Search Rules:

1. Search the word existence in all the fields.
2. The searching goes like *A* & *B* & *C* regardless the order of the search keys; regardless if beginning or ending or in between a full text.

**Word Pool:**

   Angular 
   Boot
   Strap
   xxAngular xxBoot
   xxBootxx xxAngularxx
   Angular Boot Strap

**Search Word:**

Boot Angular

**Expected Results:**

   xxAngular xxBoot
   xxBootxx xxAngularxx
   Angular Boot Strap

The current query is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM myTable
WHERE LOWER( field1 || ' ' || field 2 || ' ' || field3 )
LIKE LOWER ('%(Angular)% | %(Boot)%')
```

**Query Results:**

   Angular 
   Boot
   xxAngular xxBoot
   xxBootxx xxAngularxx
   Angular Boot Strap

-- To search the word in all fields it was merged into a single string where the word is being searched but I'm having a hard time on how to produce the regex for *A* & *B* & *C* .

-- The query currently uses | , this gives me records that matches any of search word. But I need to have them all existing in the record.

-- I tried using & in the query but showed no results. Is there anyway to perform this search using regex only?